# Measure fuel level using PIC MCU

Tags: microcontroller

So I found a bad fuel pump module from a 2006 Chevy Colorado, it has a ceramic resistor used for measuring the fuel level of the tank. I hooked it up to a PIC MCU like shown in the image below. What I want to do is display the "fuel" level (based on the resistance of R2) on a 16x2 LCD. I´m using the 10bit ADC on the micro.

Any tips on how/what can I improve on the circuit to get the full range of the ADC (0 - 1023)

[image]

Comment: Check what options you have for the ADC vref. If you can set it closer to 2.15V that will help.

Comment: If you really need the full range and want to use the internal ADC of the PIC you need an OPAmp. But maybe 330 steps resolution ist enough.

Comment: Look at the fuel gauge in your car. Using that gauge, I *challenge you* to figure out your actual fuel level to within ±5% just by looking at that gauge. Now look at your circuit, which already gives you 330 counts (0.3%!) resolution, over 10x better than the fuel gauge in your car. Do you really need any more resolution than that? ;-)

Comment: A higher voltage at Vin (say 12V) and an appropriate R1 will give you a wider "span". Be sure that V_pin2 is not above Vdd at R2_abs_max. A voltage clamp may be in order. BUT, as Mr. Snrub says, do you really need it? || An opamp with a gain of say +2 would do what you want while still operating from 5V.

Comment: Why do you need full range for? Just re-scale it against a known maximum value. It's simple fixed point multiplication and division.

Comment: And indeed your resolution won't get better than the weakest link in the chain. If you are using 5% or 1% resistors then that's the best resolution you can get. If you are using a shaky 5V as Vref then the noise levels on the supply is the best resolution you can get. And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few reasons not to worry about resolution of your fuel guage.

1. The fuel tank is very unlikely to have a constant cross-section versus height. Even with a linear fuel level sensor you will have errors in the reading.
2. The fuel level float may be on a swing arm. The non-linearity of the readout as a result of this may help reduce the error caused by the cross-section problem but only if it has been done properly or there is some element of luck.
3. Your voltage divider circuit is not linear.

[image]

*Figure 1. The voltage divider output versus R2 resistance.*

The combination of all the errors means that you should use the system as a fuel gauge indicator rather than a calibrated gauge. Of course it will still be useful if you make sure that it's accurate approaching "tank empty".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG7dEh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A constant current source would linearise the potentiometer voltage as voltage would now be directly proportional to resistance.*

The problem with this is that you'll need to design a CC source that will work off the 5 V supply in which case you'll probably have a constant current compliance up to 2.5 or 3 V so you would need to limit the current to 10 mA.

If you generate the constant current from the 12 V supply then you should add a Zener to limit the maximum voltage applied to the ADC. I've clamped at 4.7 V but a 5.1 V Zener might be safe enough in the event that the fuel gauge sender goes open circuit while you're connecting it up.

The second option gives you a free LED indication that current is flowing - if that's any use.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKSj4k.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. A simple 10 mA constant current source. The current is given by \$ I_{CC} = \frac {0.6} R \$.*

Answer (score 0):

Configure the MCU to use an external Vref.

Feed that Vref with a potential divider with the same ratio as the "empty" or "full" fuel sensor, *and from the same 5V source* to prevent you measuring the power supply variations.

Linearise in software if you want to solve for \$R_{sensor}\$